# Examples for Python and GtkUnixPrintDialog

Tags: python, printing, gtk3

I am trying to set up a print job in Python under Linux.

Now there is this GtkUnixPrintDialog that basically does what I need it to do, the problem is that I can't find any documentation on how to deal with it. I tried looking at the GTK3 reference docs, but that's all for C, and trying to translate those commands to Python didn't work.

I can easily get the dialog to open by adding it to my .glade file - but I can't find a way in Glade to connect the appropriate signals to it. Nor can I find a way to display it like other dialogs.

Anyone with a working example, to do a print job using the dialog?

Based on my previous question [Creating print job in gtk3/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269866/creating-print-job-in-gtk3-python) I have the code to set up the page as it has to be.

I am using reportlab libraries to create a pdf file, and that pdf file has to be printed out, preferably with a little control on which printer to use. Of course I could bypass that dialog entirely and dump it on the default printer, but the lack of documentation on that dialog irritates me as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `GtkPrintUnixDialog` is not included in introspection sources for [GTK+](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/Makefile.am?id=3.13.3#n1565). I am not sure if this is an oversight or done on purpose. However, this dialog is used internally by the higher level printing interface anyway which can be invoked with `Gtk.PrintOperation.run` by passing `Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG`. There is a complete example in the [`pygobject` sources](https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/demos/gtk-demo/demos/printing.py?id=3.13.3).